# BasicNetwork.performRequest - Unexpected response code 400 (POST)

Tags: android, android-volley

When I am trying to fetch data through rest api using Volley StringRequest or JsonObjectRequest. I always get 400 error. Its working fine with the postman. Http request method is POST, Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I have also checked my parameter spelling and it looks fine to me. I have tried with both StringRequest and JsonObjectRequest, result is E/Volley: [10283] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400. Below is my code. I have attached a screenshot.

[image]

Here is the new screenshot
[image: Error in code]

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    viewHelper.hideDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                    viewHelper.hideDialog();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Posting parameters to login url
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("grant_type", "password");
                    params.put("username", email);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType(){
                    return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                }
            };

            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, "Authenticating User");
```

I have alos tried with volley JSONObjectRequest

```
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("grant_type", "password");
            params.put("username", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return headers;
                }
            };
```

Can anyone please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: your `JsonObjectRequest` above is GET, not POST. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java

Comment: I have change it to POST now. Still same result.

Comment: Post your Postman screenshot with headers and body data

Comment: Postman screenshot added

Comment: Try as my sample code at http://pastebin.com/5k9WaU6E

Comment: @BNK I was trying your code. But Its not getting compile due to error. Screenshot attached. Please check it.

Comment: Post new screenshot

Comment: New screenshot added

Comment: Ah, I guess that your project uses `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`. Since Google's volley does not have `public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody,
                             Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)` so you can use `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'` instead

Comment: Yes, I am using volley 1.0.0, Should I change it to "com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19"?

Comment: Yes, you can change. Actually, both Volley libs are not maintained now. If you don't like Volley, I think you should try OkHttp or Retrofit instead

Comment: Error is gone, but still getting 400 error

Comment: Use my code with your username, password and url

Comment: @BNK you saved my day. Thank you its working now. Dont know why someone down voted this question. Its a critical question for android new comers. :)

Answer (score 3):

Below is the working example of POST request using Volley library. 

Add this to your build.gradle (Module:app) - 
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        if(jsonObject.has("success")){
                            if(jsonObject.getBoolean("success") == true){
                                JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("user"));

                                Map<String, String> loginDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                loginDetails.put(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, "true");
                                loginDetails.put(ACCESS_TOKEN, jsonObject.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN));
                                loginDetails.put(USERID, userObject.getString(USERID));
                                loginDetails.put(FIRSTNAME, userObject.getString(FIRSTNAME));
                                loginDetails.put(LASTNAME, userObject.getString(LASTNAME));
                                loginDetails.put(EMAIL, userObject.getString(EMAIL));

                                session = new SessionManager(_myActivity);
                                session.setLogin(loginDetails);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("FROM_ACTIVITY", "LoginActivity");
                                startActivity(intent);
                                LoginActivity.this.finish();
                            }else{
                                btnLogin.setClickable(true);
                                btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username or Password does not matched!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        btnLogin.setClickable(true);
                        btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong, Please try agian", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    btnLogin.setClickable(true);
                    btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Posting parameters to login url
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("grant_type", "password");
                    params.put("username", email);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType(){
                    return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                }
            };

            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            // Adding request to request queue
            RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Please comment if anyone faced issue with above code.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

A 400 means bad request the data sent by the you to the server didn't follow the rules.So check your parameter or spelling of these parameter which is required by server.
So check those try again hope it work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

`Unexpected response code 400` means Bad Reuest.

This Response is caused by sending wrong parameters with the URL.

To solve:

1. Check every parameter with spelling.
2. Make sure if response is obtained in `string` or in `object`. `stringRequest` or `JSONObjectReuest`
3. Also check `Content-type`

use this as `Content-type`

```
    @Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return headers;
}
```

For `JsonObjectReuest` use:

```
 HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("name", "BLah");

JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
       try {
           Log.d("Response:", response.toString());
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
   @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       Log.d("Error: ", error.getMessage());
   }
});
```

Comment: can you please send me a working example of volley JSONObjectRequest

Comment: you did not modify the header `Content-type`.